# SQLAlchemy polymorphic update

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a class Parent and two of its subclass Child and ChildOne.
I am able to add data to each of the table and read the data.
Now I want to update Child class's row such that it becomes a row in ChildOne table that is when I update type to "old" from "young", I want the row to get deleted from child_one table and added to child table, but without losing the "id" value (which is the primary key).
Is there any way that SQLAlchemy itself handle this? or any other idea to achieve this?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, case, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///testing.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    type = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'parent',
        'polymorphic_on': case(
            [(type == "young", "child_one"), 
            (type == "old", "child")]
            )
    }


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
    school = Column(String, default="some high school")

    def __init__(self, name, school):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.school = school

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'child'
    }


class ChildOne(Parent):
    __tablename__ = "child_one"

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
    school = Column(String, default="UCLA")
    mode = Column(Boolean, default=1)
    bool = Column(Boolean, default=0)

    def __init__(self, name, type, school, mode, bool):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.school = school
        self.mode = mode
        self.bool = bool

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'child_one'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import event

# standard decorator style
@event.listens_for(Child, 'after_update')
def receive_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    "listen for the 'after_update' event"
    if target.type == "young":
        ChildOne(id=target.id)
```

But honestly, you should just be creating triggers in the database from something like this. It doesn't require overly complex sqlalchemy code.